# Is it possible to put the collapsible icon on the left side of the text? Right now it's on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOrderItems1"> Products 1 <i class="chevron fa fa-fw" ></i></div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseOrderItems1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOrderItems2"> Products 2 <i class="chevron fa fa-fw" ></i></div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseOrderItems2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>

.panel-heading .chevron:after {
    content: "\f078";   
}
.panel-heading.collapsed .chevron:after {
    content: "\f054"; 
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPxOJX

I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm only able to move the whole entire chunk around. I'm having trouble just moving the collapsible icon.

Comment: Put the icon to the left of your text instead of the right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your HTML code to place your  icon before the text :

```
<div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOrderItems1"> <i class="chevron fa fa-fw" ></i> Products 1 </div>
```